# more robust regular expression lookaround

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

This is the input string: `$table_prefix  = 'wp5t3s1tc_';` which is part of a larger config file.

I want to match anything between the `''`

The expression I have working is `(?<=\$table_prefix(\s{2}=\s\'))(.*)?(?=\')` which is not great because of the brittle way the lookaround works with the whitespace character either side of the `=`. If the config file changes with multiple spaces either side of the `=` then the expression won't work.

I am thinking it should look more like `(?<=\$table_prefix(\s*\=\s*\'))(.*)?(?=\')` but that of course does not work.

Could someone briefly explain a more elegant way of doing this match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using `grep`. It is not very elegant, but it should be robust if you are concerned about variable spaces around the `=`.

Since variable length assertions are not allowed in `grep`, AFAIK, the only thing I can think of is to perform the extraction in two stages:

`grep -oP '(?<=\$table_prefix).*(?='"'"')' file_name | grep -oP '(?<='"'"').*'`

I'm basically capturing all the spaces around the `=` first, along with `'wp5t3s1tc_`, and then extracting everything after the `'`. The weird `'"'"'` is to escape the single quote character.

Or you could use `sed` instead of the second `grep`:

`grep -oP '(?<=\$table_prefix).*(?='"'"')' file_name | sed 's/ *= *'"'"'//'`

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I would never how figured that out myself!

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use lookaround at all as long you are guaranteed that the ' character won't appear in the sequence you are trying to match. You can use greedy search with complementary regular set, which will result in finite automata that will match greedily any string that will not contain the ' character.

To parse only the subsequence in the single quotes, use named groups (or unnamed groups if your engine does not support that. In this case, you will have to access the group by it's index instead of given name).
This regular expression does what you seek:

```
\$table_prefix\s*=\s*'(?<match>[^'.]*)';
```

Check with http://rubular.com/

Comment: No, do not check with a web thing unless you can absolutely guarantee that it is the same regex engine.

Comment: He did not mention the regex engine he is using. More on that, all the things I used are pretty much in a standard definition for all new regular expressions. These works in .NET, Java, Ruby, new Perl regexs ...

Comment: No, that’s not true.  For example, you need Java v7 and Perl v5.10 to run those.  Always test the tool you’re going to use *with that very tool and no other*.

Comment: @alan I am the Terminal in mac osx, I think that is the Perl style.
I just am not comfortable with the terminal. I will try and run a test with the grep command.

Comment: @tchrist - very valid point. I am not that confident with the terminal yet.

Comment: @Simon You will find that `perl` and `grep` use different regex syntaxes, even if you have a `-P` option to your version of grep (which MacOS does not). The most important question is what is your target programming language, tool, or library that you hope to use this regex in?

Comment: @tchrist - it is intended to be run in the terminal in bash. I am trying to write a shell script which reads a text file. I just need to extract a string so it can be stored as bash variable. ( I am realising how very little I know in this conversation - thank you)